# How can I read data and display them with C language?

Tags: c

I have to make a program which can read 'score.dat' file. Hereby, in the 'score.dat' there are 20 integers saved in binary form. Therefore, in this program when I read the 'score.dat' file I have to reconvert binary form of 20 integers in to normal integers form. But my program only shows a single binary code rather than reading the whole file.

[image]
this are the integers saved in binary form in 'score.dat' and I have to read this and display them as numbers in my option 1.

Please help!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen("score.dat", "r");

    int input;
    char temp[100];


    while (input != 3)
    {
        printf("1. Read and display all data from 'score.dat' \n");
        printf("2. Multiply all the numbers in 'score.dat' by 2. \n");
        printf("3. Quit. \n");
        printf("Enter your option: ");

        scanf("%d", &input);

        printf("\n");

        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), filepointer);
                printf("%s\n", temp);
                printf("\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to open the file for reading in binary mode (`rb`), instead of text mode (`r`), then use `fread()` (not `fgets()`) to extract the values.

Comment: Note that `printf("%s\n", temp)` will stop at the first null byte in `temp`.  If the data is binary data, it is likely that there are lots of null bytes in it.  (You should check the result of `fopen()` before using the pointer returned.  Your program will probably crash if you don't and it fails to open the file.)

Comment: How can I use fread function? I am sorry but I can't understand how the function of fread() works... T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at how the [`fgets()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) function works.

> The C library function `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

I'm guessing that each of the binary numbers are separated by a newline, and in that case, `fgets()` is designed to stop reading at that point. Try to think about how to get around that.

Also you need to open your file in reading binary mode (`rb`) instead of text mode (`r`).

Comment: the comments below your question are also valuable!

Comment: fgets() reads a *string* from the input, and since you are reading binary data, it's not the right choice. Use fread(). Something like: int num[20];
fread(num, sizeof(int), 20, fp); // read 20 objects of size int

Comment: How can I use fread function? I am sorry but I can't understand how the function of fread() works... T.T

Comment: Read the documentation and examples. I learned the hard way people dont appreciate those types of questions. bit of a professional setting

Comment: I personally love this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-structure-file-c/